# How to change Moodle Skin with HTML5?

Tags: html, moodle

I would like to change the front end layout of Moodle in HTML5. How can I do that?

For example, can I change the Moodle login page entirely in HTML5?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Requests for tools are off-topic here so I've rephrased your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For change the layout(html) of moodle, you need to work on moodle theme. 
Basically moodle themes can have various layout files like
**frontpage, general page(inner page), login page, course page etc.**

So for change the html on particular layout file, you can do work on that particular layout file.

Here you can get more information about how to work on moodle theme.

[Creating moodle theme.](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme)